# Is it safe to localize the "#" (pound sign, hashtag) as an ordinal indicator? (e.g. "#1", "#2")

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, translation, nslocalizedstring

We have a list of numbered reports that we display in our app - the numbering is important since the number of the report indicates the order it was created in, and gives the user a unique identifier to discuss the report with other users.

In a coworker's pull request, they're displaying text in labels in the UI for the cells which represent the reports with something like this:

```
label.text = "#\(report.userFacingNumber)"
```

This has the effect of numbering the reports correctly in english (i.e. "#1", "#2", etc) but I'm  not sure that this will make sense in other languages.

1. Is the pound sign universal for indicating the ordinal of a list item? If not, is there an example language where this doesn't localize correctly that I could use to prove my point?
2. Is there a way in Swift/Foundation to correctly localize this ordinal listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is the pound sign universal for indicating the ordinal of a list item?"

No it is not. Many languages use N° or other symbols.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Usage_in_North_America

> "Is there a way in Swift/Foundation to correctly localize this ordinal listing?"

*Maybe* there is a `NumberFormatter` that does this correctly, but I am not sure.

Your best bet is likely to omit the symbol.